# React Native: Error:"Cannot read property 'name' of undefined, " Although object which contains name is not undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react and working on a project in react native. I have loaded data from the server using fetch, Data is available, if i console it shows up, but when i render the data it show undefined. Being from angular background i know the data is available late for rendering, if i put some conditions then the error will go away. What i want is not to put condition on every single variable, What is the better way to manage it like we use "`*ngIf`" in **Angular** on whole content, show only if data is available. what i tried so far is below.

***Fetching Data***

```
componentDidMount() {
this._fetchData();


}

  _fetchData = () => {
    if (this.state.loading) { return; }
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    let typr = this._returnReqType(this.state.requestType)
    let include = [
      'application',
      'association:id,name',
      'unit:id,unit_number',
      'status_history',
      'status_history.user',
    ];
    EservicesService.getEservicesRequestDetails(this.state.requestId, typr, include).then(response => {
      console.log(response.record); // {prop1:'XXXXXXX',association:{name:'Association 1', ...}, ... }
      console.log(response.record.association); // {name:'Association 1', ...}
      this.setState({
        error: response.error || null,
        loading: false,
        request: response.record
      });

    }).catch(error => {
      this.setState({ error, loading: false });
    });



    }
```

***Rendering Data***

```
render() {
console.log(this.state.request); // {prop1:'XXXXXXX',association:{name:'Association 1', ...}, ... }
console.log(this.state.request.association); // {name:'Association 1', ...}
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <ScrollView>
      <Card >
        <Text>Association: {this.state.request.association_id}</Text>
        <Text>Unit: {this.state.request.association.name}</Text> {// Error Here "Cannot read 'name' of undefined" 
        }
      </Card>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since fetch is an async call, So for initial render we wont get any data and hence it is throwing error. So in order to avoid these exceptions we should check for the values before doing any operation.

```
render() {
console.log(this.state.request); // {prop1:'XXXXXXX',association:{name:'Association 1', ...}, ... }
const {request} = this.state;
console.log(request.association); // {name:'Association 1', ...}
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <ScrollView>
      <Card >
        <Text>Association: {request.association_id && request.association_id}</Text>
        <Text>Unit: {request.association.name && request.association.name}</Text> {// Error Here "Cannot read 'name' of undefined" 
        }
      </Card>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
);}
```

Comment: `TypeError: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'request.association.name')`, `<Text>Unit: {request.association && request.association.name}</Text>` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the name is available, then render it.

```
{ this.state.request.association && <Text>
 Unit: {this.state.request.association.name && this.state.request.association.name}
</Text>
}
```

Comment: How is that going to help if `this.state.request.association` is undefined?

Comment: whats the logic in putting `&&` operator in same variable. like you suggested `{this.state.request.association.name && this.state.request.association.name}`?

Comment: @ImdadAli It's a conditional rendering logic to first make sure the variable is available. It is the same as writing `this.state.request.association.name ? doSomething : doAnotherThing` this will prevent the UI from breaking when the `name` variable is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent "falsy" render while fetching the data, you could simply put check for loading state in render function. Like this:

```
render() {
  if (this.state.loading) {
    return null
  }

  return <>Your fetched data</>
}
```

Comment: not working... my loading initial state is `false`. if i make it `true` white screen shows up.

Comment: @ImdadAli It is because of this line `if (this.state.loading) { return; }`. Try to remove it so you can load data and leave loading initial state to true.